# What is inconsistent accessibility error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, interface

i am using custom role provider for that i made a `CustomRoleProvider` class and implemented some `RoleProvider` methods in it, like this

```
 public class CustomRoleProvider: RoleProvider
 {
 public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

All the methods are public.but it showing error that

> Error 4-Inconsistent accessibility: base class
>   'RoleProviderExample.RoleProvider' is less accessible than class
>   'RoleProviderExample.CustomRoleProvider'.

Where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Your base class isn't public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base class `RoleProvider` that you are exposing via `CustomeRoleProvider` is not `public`.

If you declare `RoleProvider` as `public` the error will go away. You don't have to give `RoleProvider` a `public` constructor.

---

Alternatively you could reduce the accesibility of `CustomRoleProvider` to that of `RoleProvider`. This may be the most appropriate answer, do you need to expose `CustomRoleProvider` outside the assembly?

---

If `RoleProvider` is an interface then, by convention, it is misnamed, you could rename it to `IRoleProvider`. In any case, it is still less accesible then `CustomRoleProvider`.

Make it public like this,

```
public interface IRoleProvider
{
    void CreateRole(string roleName);

    bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole);
}
```

If you don't specify the accesibility of an `interface`, `class` or `struct`, `internal` is implied.

`interface` members are always `public`. `class` and `struct` members are `private` unless specified.

It is good practice to specify, except in the case of interface members which are always `public`.

Your implementation could look like this, the `override` keyword should not be used for interface implementations, unless they are overriding an overridable base class implementation.

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : IRoleProvider
{
    public void CreateRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

if you want to explicity implement the interface,

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : IRoleProvider
{
    public void IRoleProvider.CreateRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IRoleProvider.DeleteRole(
        string roleName, 
        bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: but RoleProvider is an interface, CustomRoleProvider is a class, which is already public. How can i make RoleProvider interface public?

Comment: @Anand Interface members are automatically **public**.

Comment: @Anand, I've expanded my answer with all the salient detail I can. I hope it helps to clean up your understanding and improves the general readability of your code.

Answer (score 5):

You should make your `RoleProvider` class `public` also.

```
public class RoleProvider 
{
   ...
}
```

Base classes can't be less accessible than derived classes. Your `RoleProvider` class has probably has less [`access modifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) than `CustomRoleProvider` class.

```
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    interface RoleProvider
    {
           void CreateRole(string roleName);

           bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole);
    }
```

Actually, you don't have to write `public` keyword on interfaces. Interface members are automatically `public`. They can't include any access modifiers.

Comment: but RoleProvider is an interface, CustomRoleProvider is a class, which is already public. How can i make RoleProvider interface public?

Comment: @Anand, If `RoleProvider` is an interface then the `override` keyword is spurious and misleading, as is the naming of `RoleProvider`.

Comment: @Jodrell OP wants to write them. If he wants to change them, they are deletable of course..

Answer (score 0):

It means that you've defined `RoleProvider` ... but to be a private class (is this true?). Try making RoleProvider a `public`.

Comment: `protected` is still less accesible than `public`

Comment: My bad. Learned from the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing access specifier of RoleProvider class to either public or internal.