# C# Inconsistent accessibility error

Tags: c#

I am having trouble to fix the errors in my object oriented program in C#. The program has 9 classes and in the one class.  The Error is  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Employee.Employee' is less accessible than method 'Employee.EmployeeInput.CollectEmployeeInfo(Employee.Employee)' 
on the coding

```
    public static void CollectEmployeeInfo(Employee theEmployee)
    {
        theEmployee.Firstname = InputUtilities.getStringInputValue("First Name");
        theEmployee.Lastname = InputUtilities.getStringInputValue("Last name");
        theEmployee.Gender = InputUtilities.getCharInputValue("Gender");
        theEmployee.Dependents = InputUtilities.getIntegerInputValue("# Dependents");
    }
```

the CollectEmployeeInfo is what is showing the error and I am not sure what has to be done to the other classes to fix the error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
class Employee
{
    public const double MIN_SALARY = 20000;
    public const double MAX_SALARY = 100000;
    public const int MIN_DEPENDENTS = 0;
    public const int MAX_DEPENDENTS = 10;
    public const string DEFAULT_NAME = "not given";
    public const char DEFAULT_GENDER = 'U';
    public const string DEFAULT_TYPE = "Generic Employee";

    protected string firstName;
    protected string lastName;
    protected double annualSalary;
    protected char gender;
    protected int dependents;
    protected static int numEmployees = 0;
    protected Benefits employeeBenefits;
    protected string employeeType;

    public Employee()
    {
        firstName = DEFAULT_NAME;
        lastName = DEFAULT_NAME;
        annualSalary = MIN_SALARY;
        dependents = MIN_DEPENDENTS;
        numEmployees++;
        employeeBenefits = new Benefits();
    }
    public Employee(string firstname, string lastname, char gender, int dependents, double annualsalary, Benefits employeeBenefits)
    {
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
        AnnualSalary = annualsalary;
        Gender = gender;
        Dependents = dependents;
        EmployeeBenefits = employeeBenefits;
        numEmployees++;
    }
    public Benefits EmployeeBenefits
    {
        get { return employeeBenefits; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                employeeBenefits = new Benefits();
            else
                employeeBenefits = value;
        }
    }
    public Employee(string employeeType)
        : this()
    {
        EmployeeType = employeeType;
    }
    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                firstName = DEFAULT_NAME;
            else
                firstName = value;
        }
    }
    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                lastName = DEFAULT_NAME;
            else
                lastName = value;
        }
    }
    public double AnnualSalary
    {
        get { return annualSalary; }
        set
        {
            if (value > MIN_SALARY & value < MAX_SALARY)
                annualSalary = value;
            else if (value < MIN_SALARY)
                annualSalary = MIN_SALARY;
            else
                annualSalary = MAX_SALARY;
        }
    }
    public char Gender
    {
        get { return gender; }
        set
        {
            if (value == 'F')
                gender = value;

            else if (value == 'f')
                gender = value;

            else if (value == 'M')
                gender = value;

            else if (value == 'm')
                gender = value;

            else
                gender = DEFAULT_GENDER;
        }
    }
    public int Dependents
    {
        get { return dependents; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= MIN_DEPENDENTS & value <= MAX_DEPENDENTS)
                dependents = value;
            else if (value < MIN_DEPENDENTS)
                dependents = MIN_DEPENDENTS;
            else
                dependents = MAX_DEPENDENTS;
        }
    }
    public static int NumEmployees
    {
        get { return numEmployees; }
    }
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get { return firstName + " " + lastName; }
    }
    public string EmployeeType
    {
        get { return employeeType; }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                employeeType = DEFAULT_TYPE;
            else
                employeeType = value;
        }
    }
    public double CalculatePay()
    {
        return annualSalary / 52;
    }
    public double CalculatePay(double modifiedSalary)
    {
        AnnualSalary = modifiedSalary;
        return AnnualSalary / 52;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string output;

        output = "\n============ Employee Information ============";
        output += "\n\t         Type:\t" + employeeType;
        output += "\n\t         Name:\t" + firstName + " " + lastName;
        output += "\n\t       Gender:\t" + gender;
        output += "\n\t   Dependents:\t" + dependents;
        output += "\n\tAnnual Salary:\t" + annualSalary.ToString("C2");
        output += "\n\t   Weekly Pay:\t" + CalculatePay().ToString("C2");
        output += "\n\t" + employeeBenefits.ToString();

        return output;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is inconsistent accessibility error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625023/what-is-inconsistent-accessibility-error)

Comment: Does this method have to be `static`?

Comment: If you don't include anything in front of `class` it [defaults to `internal` not `public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

Comment: Do not edit your question to ask a new question. Open a new question up to do that (which you did, but you should have rolled back the change here too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the types you need to pass to a method must be at least as accessible as that method.  If `Employee` is a private or internal class it can't be passed to this method from outside that class/assembly.

Make `Employee` public and it should work.

Comment: The Employee class is public just there is 8 variables that are protected such as Firstname, Lastname, Gender, and Dependents

Comment: @Jess then copy the code of Employee to your original post and prove it, because your error is saying it is not.

Comment: @Jess That's what the error message is telling you - `'Employee.Employee' is less accessible than [public]`.  Maybe check to see there isn't another `Employee` class defined somewhere that the compiler is using instead?

Comment: @Jess If you don't specify, classes default to `protected`.  Add `public` in front of `class Employee` and that should fix the problem.

Comment: Once I changed it to  public class Employee   I got 2 more errors

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin the default is [`internal` not `protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx). You actually can't mark a class as protected (unless it is inside another class)

Comment: @Jess, well you would have to edit your question and tell us what those errors are. If they are more "less accessable" error you have to go to the classes the error mentions and mark those public too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Right you are. Thanks, I don't know why I thought that - it doesn't even make sense. Probably something half-remembered from my Java days.

Answer (score 2):

`Employee` type should be not less accessible than `CollectEmployeeInfo`.

So `Employee` should be defined as `public` "at least"