# Inconsistent Accessibility Error #2

Tags: c#, accessibility

Help I'm getting this error:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'SharpUpdate.SharpUpdateXml' is less accessible than method
>   'SharpUpdate.SharpUpdateInfoForm.SharpUpdateInfoForm(SharpUpdate.iSharpUpdateable,
>   SharpUpdate.SharpUpdateXml)'

From this code:

```
namespace SharpUpdate
{
    public class SharpUpdateInfoForm : Form
    {
        public SharpUpdateInfoForm(
            iSharpUpdateable applicationInfo,
            SharpUpdateXml updateInfo)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon != null)
                this.Icon = applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon;
            this.Text = applicationInfo.ApplicationName + "- Update Info";
            this.lblVersions.Text = String.Format(
                "Current Version:  {0}\nUpdate Version: {1}",
                applicationInfo.ApplicationAssembly.GetName().Version.ToString(),
                updateInfo.Version.ToString());
            this.txtDescription.Text = updateInfo.Description;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried changing `public` to `internal` and `private`, but the error remained the same.

Comment: It looks as though `SharpUpdate.SharpUpdateXml` isn't a public type, try changing it to public.

Comment: Has searching here for [Inconsistent Accessibility Error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Inconsistent+Accessibility+Error) helped?

Comment: What modifier (internal, public) does the `SharpUpdateXml` class have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Inconsistent accessibility error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223027/c-sharp-inconsistent-accessibility-error)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is fairly self-explanatory. It boils down to the following:

> parameter type SharpUpdateXml is less accessible than method SharpUpdateInfoForm

The `SharpUpdateInfoForm` is of course the constructor of your form. The constructor is public and the `SharpUpdateXml` class passsed to the constructor is less accessible (either private or internal). You have to make the `SharpUpdateXml` class public or `SharpUpdateInfoForm` internal (or private if `SharpUpdateXml` is private).

In current scenario you expose your `SharpUpdateInfoForm` to everyone (public) but to initialize it you have to use `SharpUpdateXml` which is not available to everyone (private/internal). So a user of your classes can try to initialize the form but may not be allowed to use `SharpUpdateXml` which makes whole setup bit useless.